# Ruby on Rails Requests Taking 30+ Seconds to Reach Client

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services

This is a weird one.

We have a Rails app that's hosted in AWS North America. It's basically a backend server for a game our team in Isreal is making.

To run the game they send a request on login to our server to retrieve ~50k lines of json.

Our server tends to take 500-800 ms on average give or take, most of that is spent serializing json which seems in line.

Here's an example:

```
13 Jan 2022 18:24:40.5672022-01-13 18:24:40 +0000 severity=INFO, method=GET path=/api/sdk/v1/appusers/48DACA13-E7A8-515F-BA6C-DF511E3FE702/remote_configs format=json controller=Api::Sdk::V1::RemoteConfigsController action=index status=200 duration=348.72 view=150.53 db=1.21 ip= session_id=61e06e60c714330555edc1f8 appuser_external_id=48DACA13-E7A8-515F-BA6C-DF511E3FE702
```

That call ended up timing out in the client after 30 seconds with no response back from the server.

Essentially there are 29+ unaccounted seconds of time happening between them receiving the call, even though the server seems to be working reasonably fast.

Any ideas how to debug or what might be going on? Or ideas of what we should do? Having a duplicate server/database in every single region in the world we want to support doesn't seem like a reasonable route.

Comment: Have you tested the connection speed between the team in israel and the server? 50k lines of json can be quite a few MB of data and transferring that might take some time on a slow connection even after the server has completed making it.

Comment: Do you have a firewall or any restriction on the length of the response on your http server? Clearly, problem does not come from you app directly. Logs are clear.
Did you try to ping from Israel's computer to North America's server?

Comment: @brcebn - no firewall or length restrictions right now. We're waiting for them to encounter the issue again and then asked them to hit us via Postman. Unfortunately it seems to be intermittent, so randomly their game just won't load if they don't get the server response back.

Comment: @SiimLiiser that was one of our first thought but on their side the speeds per their speedtests do seem to be good. What my main worry is that somewhere between our server and their client that's on a fast connection is some kind of clog or slowdown that periodically happens to cause this. I'm struggling to figure out how to identify, diagnose and hopefully fix that clog if it exists :)

Comment: If you can ask them to traceroute a query, you'll have all jumps between them and your servers to identify if your idea of slowdown is accurate or not.